# Boxes linked by 'smart lines' - what's this called ? How's it done?

Tags: algorithm, terminology

*Terminology question !*

In many graphics packages the user can draw a line between two objects (two boxes say) and then when the user moves one of the one boxes subseqently the line moves to keep the (visual) connection in place.

I want to learn more about this functionality might be implemented (really good to find some open source code to read).

So I want to find some terminology for what this type of stuff is called. I saw a reference on stackoverflow to 'wire-based drawing' but that seems to have been an invention of the author rather than a generally used term.

Is there a proper term for this area of graphics software technology ? Any open source libraries that implement it ?

thanks

Comment: Dunno what it's called but here's an open source example: http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/graphicsview-diagramscene.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that most common name is "connectors". You can draw them using [pathfinding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pathfinding) algorithm (depends on how your objects are represented)

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFDiagramDesigner_Part1.aspx) is an example of designer that implements what you described.

Comment: Great that (and the links) was just what I was after.

Answer (score 1):

Diagrams - bloc, flowchart and so on. This type of drawings is usually created by software like [Visio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visio) and [Dia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dia_(software)).

Btw, Dia is open source, so you can look at it to see how this is implemented.

Comment: Thanks for your reply - hadn't thought about Dia even though I've used it in the past - will take a look.

Answer (score 0):

These are connectors.

[OpenOffice.org](http://www.openoffice.org/) implements them. The feature is available in the Writer, Draw and Impress components (the Connectors menu on the Drawing toolbar). However, I have no idea how easy it would be to dig that feature out of their source code. Nevertheless, OpenOffice.org is open source.